# Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter: Should use View Holder pattern -crash the app

Tags: java, android

i have warning that cause crash my app.

it is the warning ::

> (((( Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter: Should use View Holder pattern (use recycled view passed into this method as the second parameter) for smoother scrolling))))

it is my code ::

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contacts> {

    Context mCtx;
    int layoutRes ;
    List<Contacts> contactsList;


    public ContactsAdapter(Context mCtx, int layoutRes, List<Contacts> 
                   contactsList)
       {

        super(mCtx, layoutRes, contactsList);

        this.mCtx = mCtx ;
        this.layoutRes = layoutRes ;
        this.contactsList = contactsList ;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
      public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, 
                            @NonNull 
      ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);

            View view = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null);

            TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewContactMessage);

            Contacts contacts = contactsList.get(position);

            textView.setText(contacts.getPhone());

            textView.setText(contacts.getContext());

            return view;
        }

    }
```

> warning is in line :::
>   View view = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null);

and it is my MessageActivity code ::

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    List<Contacts> contactsList;
    ListView listView;

    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        mDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(MainActivity.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        contactsList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewContactMessage);

        loadContact_dbFromDatabase();
    }


    private void loadContact_dbFromDatabase(){
        String sql = " SELECT * FROM contact_message";
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

            do {
                contactsList.add(new Contacts (
                    cursor.getInt(0),
                    cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(2)
                ));

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());

                ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(this, R.id.textViewContactMessage, contactsList);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

i know that other said this question but i do not know how to change my code!!!

can any say to me what should i do??!!

Comment: How do you use this adapter? Could you show your code?

Comment: @anil  yes i edit my code

Comment: @anil did you see the code again???

Comment: You need to realize ViewHolder pattern as in answer below. But I advise you to use CursorAdapter or (if you want to use your own adapter) RecyclerView instead of ListView

Comment: @anil i want to use RecyclerView but i do not know how to use it!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating another view inside the convertview,that's why you are getting error here.

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null);
```

Try the below code where I have put the listview row in a static inner class.

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
      public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView,               
      @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new Holder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null);
            viewHolder.textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewContactMessage);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();   
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    private static class Holder {
        TextView textView;
    }
}
```

Comment: with your code for the first time i can go to this view but when i add something in the view when again i go to view the app has crashed .  have you any idea???!!!

Comment: Check the logs and let me know where it's crashing then I might be able to help you. Like the below answer suggested you should initialize LayoutInflater in the constructor.

Comment: i search and change my code to RecyclerView and it works fun .thnks bro

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize your layout inflater in constructor and not in `getView()`.

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
public ContactsAdapter(Context mCtx, int layoutRes, List<Contacts> 
                   contactsList)
       {
    super(mCtx, layoutRes, contactsList);

    this.mCtx = mCtx ;
    this.layoutRes = layoutRes ;
    this.contactsList = contactsList ;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
```

in `getView()`, inflate your layout

```
view = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null);
```

and also you have to use view holder as @Padmini S suggested